# How can I know who have voted up my comment? 

Tags: support, comments, voting

Is there any way(as I really don't know) to get the list of persons who have voted on my comments.

Comment: @anonymous voters: please always come with comment for improvements, while voting down. person would die with curiosity in mind, What he did wrong. ;)

Comment: Down-votes have a bit of a different meaning in meta.SO. They are simply to indicate "I do not agree [with this proposal]." While you are not specifically suggesting any changes, the down-votes are mostly like folks expressing the opinion "no, we do not want this."

Comment: However, asking for explanations on downvotes inevitably leads to a flurry of downvotes anyway; some people think it's funny - I made the mistake of asking myself once.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there isn't.

All up/down votes are anonymous.

Comment: Also to users with 500000 reputation?